# Master Import (using) file c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So I have many classes for a unity video game and it is growing VERY quickly, however
I am using quite a few assets to help and as a result I have many using  that
are repeated on each class.

Is there a way in c# or unity to have a master file that just contains all of them for example

```
namespace MasterImports {
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
}
```

then just adding something like this to each class by default.

```
using MasterImports;
```

I just think this makes managment of my skripts alot easier and
means I am unlikely to run into an error where I forget to add a using
then forgetting what one it was i used and having to hunt scripts for it.

Comment: This does not work in C#. A using declaration for namespaces is not the same as an include in C++. You will have to include everything that you need at the top of the file. If you use a somewhat decent IDE, you can auto-include stuff while writing code.

Comment: C# using are not working additive like header files. Each individual script needs to have the `using` statements for the type it uses.

Answer (score -1):

This is a deliberate rule of C#. If you do this:

```
namespace Frobozz
{
    namespace Magic
    {
        class Lamp {}
    }

    class Foo
    {
        Magic.Lamp myLamp; // Legal; Magic means Frobozz.Magic when inside Frobozz
    }
}
```

That is legal. But this is not:

```
namespace Frobozz
{
    namespace Magic
    {
        class Lamp {}
    }
}

namespace Flathead
{
    using Frobozz;
    class Bar
    {
        Magic.Lamp myLamp; // Illegal; merely using Frobozz does not bring Magic into scope
    }
}
```

Look into [namespace aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/dfb3cx8s(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

```
using n2 = n1.n2;

...
n2.foo something;
```

What is before the class name should be a complete name space (with/or other class name(s) for nested types). A truncated namespace will not work.

Comment: That's true but how is it related to what OP asks? Your answer is about nested namespaces while OP is asking for the possibility of coupling all `using` statements into one single one .. which doesn't exist in c#

Comment: since there is no way i am just putting some other workarounds that he can still use. Whenever i see you you are always giving negative to people man. Not a good attitude. Try to be more positive.

Comment: Pointing out that your answer is not on topic for the scope of the question has nothing to do with attitude. We are working hard to keep StackOverflow a high quality Q&A community. Please refer to [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). What you provided as said is true but not at all a valid alternative to what OP is asking about ;)

Comment: Fair enough then :)

Comment: Thank you all for the response. It sucks c# does not have this feature its so nice. Out of self hatred, is there any reason why they do not have it or just not a feature that was ever added. 

The only think I could think is that .net application maybe compile each section as its own sorta micro part and thats why but i am just guessing to be honest, im a noob at c#